# Problemas ao instalar phpMyAdmin - dbconfig-* quebrado

Tags: php, mysql, linux, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

Estou com um problema na tentativa de instalar o phpMyAdmin em meu Ubuntu Server 16.04. Instalei o MySQL normalmente, porém quando vou instalar o PMA, ocorre o seguinte erro nos pacotes dependentes dbconfig-common, dbconfig-mysql e dbconfig-no-tanks:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu já garimpei a internet atrás de uma solução, já tentei instalar esses pacotes manualmente, já purguei todos os pacotes referentes e nada deu certo.
Alguém já teve problema semelhante? Poderiam me ajudar?

Versão do Ubuntu: 16.04

Obrigado desde já

Comment: Versão do ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Cara eu entendo que ta faltando a configuracao do "dbconfig"
tenta executar

#### $ sudo mysql_secure_installation

Caso nao funcione, tente outra abordagem como reinstalar o db-config e reconfigurar o PhpMyAdmin

#### $sudo apt purge dbconfig-common

#### $sudo apt install --reinstall dbconfig-mysql

#### $sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin

Comment: Muito bom Danilo. Deu certo. Consegui executar o PMA, só que lá no servidor, ainda continua dando esse erro toda vez que executo dpkg ou apt ou apt-get. Ou seja, não cnsigo instalar mais nada por que tá "travado"